# Modifying Daily View in Telescope

Tags: telescope

It's been quite difficult to me to modify the "Daily View" without breaking the app, despite trying to do something rather simple: I would like to display the forthcoming posts instead of the past posts when hitting the load button.

I made the postedAt attribute accessible to ["member"] in order to make this use of Telescope relevant.

If anyone can share a few tips, that would be great !

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't realize moment.js was involved, so:

```
date: moment().add(i, 'days').startOf('day').toDate()
```

That simple!